# Laravel: ReflectionException (-1) HELP Class pia-distribution does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

I've picked up a legacy project with a bug in it and my Laravel skills are at noob level. I'm getting the error above and I've managed to trace the error to the following code.

```
\App::make('pia-distribution', array(base_path() . '/resources/ios/' . 
Input::get('environment') . '/' . Input::get('version') . '/app.ipa', 
Input::get('environment'), Input::get('version')));
```

I've done a project search on `pia-distributon` and this is the only place it is found. Is there a class that's supposed to exist?

I'm unfamiliar with how `App::make` works and could use some help on solving this bug. Thanks

Comment: What laravel version is this?

Comment: it's Laravel 4.2

Comment: You can read up on [IoC](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc) basically there should be a place where `pia-distribution` is bound in the IoC container otherwise the app doesn't know how to make it. If there's no such place I'm going to guess that you either got buggy code (so you can just comment out the erroring line for now until you've figured out what it's supposed to be doing) or you've have not gotten the complete code.